# How to prevent attributes initialization with certain values in Python

Tags: python, fractions

I'm new to Python, currently writing a code for a Fraction class:

```
class Fraction:
    def __init__(self, numerator, denominator):
        self.numerator = numerator
        self.denominator = denominator

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s/%s" % (self.numerator, self.denominator)

    def __mul__(self, other):
        return "%s/%s" % (self.numerator* other.numerator, self.denominator* other.denominator)
```

However, I want to prevent defining a fraction with `denominator = 0`, since this is not allowed in maths. How do I accomplish this?
I have tried putting a `try-except` block in `__init__` function and also an `if-else` condition but none of that seems to work.

Thanks in advance!
Daniel

Comment: `__mul__` should return a new instance of `Fraction` , not a string, otherwise you won't be able to write, for example, `fract1 * fract2 * fract3`.

Answer (score 3):

You can raise an exception as one option

```
if denominator == 0: 
     raise ValueError("Denominator must not be zero")
```